# How to sort by columns in a cgi web page

Tags: javascript, sql, perl

I have a CGI file written in Perl. I query data from a sqlserver using DBI and display it on the html page from a single table. The web page displays the data in six columns such as firstname, lastname, DOB etc. When the data loads, the server side query is ordered by just the DOB. However after it is displayed on the page, when the users click on the column headers such as firstname or lastname, I want to sort the values by those columns. Not sure whether it could be done at the client side using javascript or has to be done at the server side. Any help is greatly appreciated. I saw similar question already in the stackoverflow database, but not much useful.
Thanks

Comment: Doing it server side is probably easier as it already does the job for DOB. You just need to request the same page again adding a querystring parameter like ``order=otherCol``. Then modify the Perl script to check that parameter and use it in the ``ORDER BY`` clause of the SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Currently the column headers are displayed using <TH> tags. Should I make them into buttons? Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't. Use links instead: ``<th><a href="page?order=otherCol">Header</a></th>``. If you want to make it look nice, add css classes so you can display up or down arrows next to the relevant column to indicate the current sorting.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done server-side as mentioned by @acfrancis in the comments, or it could be done client-side with something like [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar before with Slickgrid.  It might take a bit of playing to get exactly what you're looking for (depending on your Javascipt background), but once you get familiar with it, Slickgrid can do some pretty neat things with tabular data, including sorting, filtering, etc.

[Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)